# MyV4PrintDriver error- Visual Studio 2022

Tags: printing, driver, wdk, v4-printer-driver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfZY1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6qKB.png)

I am trying to build v4 printer driver sample in visual studio 2022 but getting error. Need a solution?

My current windows configuration windows 10 with visual studio 2022

Comment: Please don't post images for text content, nor links to external code. You should take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to help people help you.